# Correlation in R between categorical and boolean variables

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I want to use the data attached to see i there is correlation between a bootcamp that students attended and the job they end up getting. For example, does someone who attended a software engineering bootcamp end up with a software job, or does attending a data science one lead to a job in data? I have tried doing this but I dont think its right. I have attached a screenshot of the data.Please help with correct code
[image: raw data]

```
data <- data[rowSums(is.na(data)) == 0,]
summary(data)
data <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
sapply(data,class)
data$Bootcamp <- as.numeric(factor(data$Bootcamp))
sapply(data,class)
data <- data[rowSums(is.na(data)) == 0,]
```

I have already looked online for similar situations but they quite address this problem